# Wordpress custom metabox, load on posts, pages, and all custom post types?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

Im trying to make my custom field load on all posts, pages, and all custom post types that are public.

But i don't know how to combine it.

This is variable that i set to load custom field on post and page

```
public function vf_add_meta_box( $post_type ) {

    if (in_array( $post_type, $this->post_types )) {
        add_meta_box( 
            $this->option_name,
            $this->metabox_name,
            array( $this, 'meta_box_display' ),
            $post_type,
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
```

$post_type is defined in other function and inserted in __construct and it's set like this

```
$post_types = array('post', 'page' );
```

And from wordpress codex instructions in order to get all custom post types you can use this code.

```
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$custom_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $custom_types  as $post_type ) {

   return $post_type ;
}
```

So i assumed if i add $post_type to $post_types array

```
$post_types = array('post', 'page', $post_type );
```

it would display metabox in custom post type but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your last foreach with this:

```
$post_types = array_merge($post_types, $custom_types);
```

That should combine your custom post types array with your default `$post_types` array.

Comment: Does it gives an error of some sort or it doesn't add the meta box ?

Comment: Another quick question, are you sending an array to the function that adds the meta boxes in the __construct function or are you doing the loop in the construct and send the variable in the loop to the function ? I'm trying to see if maybe the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Answer to 1st comment: it doesn't show anything, it just doesn't load meta box, not even on default post or page. And on 2nd comment: It's bit complicated. $post_types is defined inside function1, than on end of function1 i call new class_metabox. Than i create class class_metabox, inside i use __construct to define different variables like $this->option_name, $this->metabox_name, $this->post_types, and later on inside same class i create a function that you see in question.Everything else works even when i try $post_types = array('post', 'page', 'project', 'portfolio' ); but i need it dynamic

Comment: It turns out it's working, im honestly sorry im a bit too tired, so i probably made typo somewhere in previous tryout.